# No puedo crear una base de datos en sql server 2017 windows 10 con un usuario administrador, pero sí con el usuario de instalación de windows

Tags: sql-server-2017

No puedo crear una base de datos en sql server 2017 windows 10 con un usuario administrador, pero sí puedo con el usuario de instalación de windows.

No es igual un usuario administrador creado que el usuario de instalación primero que se crea? por lo que veo, no.

Con el de instalación creo la bd en sql server y con el otro da error 262. Veo que sysadmin dentro del usuario de instalación está marcado en sql server y con el usuario administrador no está ni se puede habilitar el check.

Como creo un usuario con todos los privilegios que tiene el que se crea en la instalación de windows? así creo que se soluciona el problema.

Gracias

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [ask]. Tu pregunta parece no relacionada con [es.so], en todo caso falta que digas si tu Servidor SQL está configurado para usar Windows Account o está en Mixed Mode. El tema pudiera estar por allí. Saludos

Comment: El acceso a sql server es para cuentas Windows.